# Is there a rosmake clean?

Tags: rosmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know about `rosmake --pre-clean`.  But what if you just want to clean your package and not build it?  There doesn't seem to be a "don't build" flag in rosmake.

When I have a new package that I want to add to my svn repository, I develop it until it is working, then remove the bin, build, and other computer generated files, then do an `svn add` on the package.  I typically remove all these directories by hand...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9520/is-there-a-rosmake-clean?/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2011-03-22

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can just do `roscd your_package_name && make clean` to clean out all the generated files from just that package. I typically use `rosmake` only when building new package the first time to make sure all dependencies are built or when dependencies change. After the initial `rosmake`, plain `make` command is much faster and only builds the package I am currently developing.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on 2011-03-22**:
Thanks for the tip.  It still would be nice to have this functionality built into rosmake.  That would allow you to clean a whole stack or all dependent packages, etc.  And you wouldn't have to be inside that package dir either.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just been informed that the `--target` option of rosmake will do what I want.  For example:

```
rosmake --target=clean
```

Thanks tfoote!

---

Originally posted by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) with karma: 794 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 21